# User id and Group id in Linux

Tags: linux, process

Kindly guide me to the tutorials where i could find information on User id (Real and Effective) and Group id (Real and Effective) with reference to Linux.

Thanks,LinuxPenseur

Comment: @Noufal I disagree.  I don't see a single comprehensive discussion of all the complexities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-more-on-user-id-password-and-group-management.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a surprisingly complicated question.  For starters, you are forgetting about the Saved UID.
I don't have an answer, but can give you some links for research:

- http://www.imodulo.com/gnu/glibc/Users-and-Groups.html
- http://www.stanford.edu/~stinson/cs155/notes/setuid.txt
- http://linux.die.net/man/2/setresuid